# React: DOM manipulation from HTML response

Tags: reactjs, react-dom

I have an API which returns a whole block of HTML. In old project (JS, jQuery... not React) I had a bunch of jQuery events declared after I got this HTML so all the clicks were working fine.

The API returns some classes and ids like this:

```
<div id="content">
<span class="span">Span 1</span><span class="span">Span 2</span>
</div>
```

And simple events:

```
$('.span').click(function (e) {
      $(this).text('Span clicked');
    });
```

Obviously it's not that simple and it fills an entire page with different DOM events. Convert it to States is not that simple unless I modify completely the response and this is something that cannot be modified from backend (and from frontend it's too much).

What's the best way in React of doing this without copying the whole jQuery events?
(I don't find it clean)

Answer (score 0):

There are more questions to be asked here but main response will be always to not bring jQuery to React.

As mentioned, there are some situations where we are sitting on the fence and we cannot wait here for a backend refactor.

Since I have React running on a old platform using JS + jQuery but I have done is move my jQuery logic to something global like this:

```
// NOTE: temporary function until API is refactored returning a json
    window.runOldJquery = function () {
    $('.span').click(function (e) {
          $(this).text('Span clicked');
        });
    }
```

So in React, I call my API and when it successes I call `window.runOldJquery`.

This is the best solution I could find for this specific scenario without bringing nothing to React.